# WordPress comments work locally only?

Tags: comments

Here's my issue:

- on localhost: comments just work for both registered & logged in users AND for guests,
- live (on-line): comments work only for registered & logged in users, comments posted by guests are "disappearing" on the way, they're not being shown under "Comments" in wp-admin, and after posting them browser scrolls all the way top instead focusing on newly added comment to approve.

Of course I have "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" unchecked. Is it possible there's some issue with my server configuration? I'm using a custom theme, but the comment system is exactly the same as in other themes from twenty* line.

Comment: Yes, it is possible there's an issue with the server config. Particularly the permissions. What server environment is it running on? What lever of access do you have to the server?

Have you noticed anything else unusual? Unable to install/remove plugins or add media?

Comment: I'm not an admin, but I will contact mine. What CHMODs do I need and on which files? Unfortunately everything else seems to work just fine... What's even stranger, I own two blogs and on one of them temporary comments appear (only for the guest who posts them) and on the other one - they don't appear at all just like in original question. In both cases they never make it to the database... :(

Comment: See [Permission Scheme for WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress). 755 on directories and 644 on files works well for my server running suPHP. These are the minimum permissions required, but you may need to go 775 and 664 respectively depending on how the server is set up. It's definitely a job for your admin if it is a permissions issue.

Comment: Form-related issues are often caused by mod_security, I would ask hosting support if it is running and if there is anything in logs related to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check if you have exceeded your database max?
I've had this before and for me this was a hosting issue.